# Handle an event in a child form while the parent form is running

Tags: c#, multithreading, mdi

Suppose that I have Form1 as a parent from in a MDI Windows forms application.
It has a btnStart button, which simply does a lot of calculation, let say:

```
double i;
while(blnContinue)
{
i=(i+1)%100000;
}
```

Form2 is a child with btnStop button, which simply assign blnContinue = false; so that the while loop breaks;

But the point is that, the Form2 cannot raise the event when the btnStop is pressed.

In this case, it's straightforward to make the function containing the while loop in a separate thread and create the btnStop in the parent form.

But I must do the "infinite" while loop in the main thread, so I it's not allowed to
make it as a thread and start/stop it.

Anyone knows how to process the event of the Form2?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call Application.DoEvents inside the loop, say every 100ms. I don't think there is any other option. Without that your entire app will appear locked and no events will fire anywhere so no chance to do anything. Is there something stopping you using another thread?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try, though I'm not sure it'll affect the performance... I have to do it in main thread since I got errors working with a driver with separate, and now I have to check if it works with the main thread....